# Laravel Lumen Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\back()

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Hello so I am working on my own authentication system using Laravel's lumen and getting the error `Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\back()` whenever I try to login with wrong credentials. This what my function looks like in my controller:

```
public function loglink(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    $user = array(
        'username' => $input['username'],
        'password' => $input['password']
    );

     if (Auth::attempt($user)) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('auth.welcome', compact('user'));
     } else {
         return back()->withInput();
     }
 }
```

Is there something I need to include/call in my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `back()` shortland in Laravel only for now. For Lumen you need to add `redirect()`:

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

Read more: http://lumen.laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects

Comment: Nice! Can you pass a variable with redirect?

Comment: @FewFlyBy can you please specify which variable you want to send with redirect?

Comment: It is not working for me in Lumen 5.6
Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Http\Redirector::back()